# Тире перед вводными словами

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

Контуры седла в вертикальной проекции соответствуют форме сечения конуса, выполненного со скосом, другими словами, эллипсу с полуосями E1 и E2.

Скажите, пожалуйста, как в данном предложении (авторская пунктуация сохранена) правильно добавить тире?

Хочется так:

Контуры седла в вертикальной проекции соответствуют форме сечения конуса, выполненного со скосом, другими словами — эллипсу с полуосями E1 и E2.

Правильно так?

Контуры седла в вертикальной проекции соответствуют форме сечения конуса, выполненного со скосом — другими словами, эллипсу с полуосями E1 и E2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем примере тире следует поставить перед вводным словом, тем самым подчеркнуть присоединительные отношения. Тире обычно ставится после вводного словосочетания,если вводное словосочетание образует неполную конструкцию (пропущено какое-либо слово, восстанавливаемое из контекста). 
Ср.: ***Чичиков велел остановиться по двум причинам: с одной стороны, чтобы дать отдохнуть лошадям, с другой — чтобы и самому отдохнуть и подкрепиться*** .

В вашем же примере вводное словосочетание приводится полностью. Обратите внимание: перед тире необходима запятая, которая закрывает причастный оборот.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Да, я тоже пыталась так рассуждать, что слово не пропущено, значит тире скорее всего будет ставиться по другим правилам, но думала, что оно возможно как интонационное.